# How to cache data publicly from firebase function?

Tags: firebase, caching, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm a little bit lost on how firebase functions work with authentication,

Suppose I have a function that pulls 100 documents and sets the cache header for 24 hours.

`res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0, s-maxage=86400' // 24 * 60 * 60`

By default, does that apply to all users or is it cached per user? There's some instances where the 100 documents are unique to the user - while other functions where the 100 documents are available to any user that's authenticated.

I see in the docs that you can set a `__session` which implies it's for individual users data, however there isn't much documentation for how to set that (or where). Is it set by default?

My goal is to have a function that requires the user be authenticated, then return 100 documents from a non-user specific collection - aka not have to read 100 documents per user. However, I don't think thats feasible because it would need to check if each user is authorized (not cacheable). So is there a way to just make a publicly available cache?

Any light that can be shared on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header is used to instruct a user's browser and any CDN edge server on how to cache the request.

For requests requiring authentication, making use of the CDN is not really possible for this as you should be using `Cache-Control: private` for these responses (the default for Cloud Functions).

While you could check that your users are authenticated and then redirect them to a publically cached resource (like `https://example.com/api/docs?sig=<somesignature>`), this URL would still be accessible if someone got hold of that URL/cached data.

Arguably the best approach would be to store your "cached" responses in a single Cloud Firestore document (if it is less than 1MB in size and is JSON-compatible) or store it in Cloud Storage.

The code included below is an example of how you could do this with a Cloud Firestore cache. I've used posts where the authenticated user is the author as an example, but for this specific use case, you would be better off using the Firebase SDK to make such a query (realtime updates, finer control, query API). A similar approach could be applied for "all user" resources.

If attempting to cache HTML or some other not JSON friendly format, I would recommend changing the caching layer to Cloud Storage. Instead of storing the post's data in the cache entry, store the path and bucket to the cached file in storage (like below). Then if it hasn't expired, get a stream of that file from storage and [pipe it through to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65683315/3068190).

```json
{
  data: {
    fullPath: `/_serverCache/apiCache/${uid}/posts.html`,
    bucket: "myBucket"
  },
  /* ... */
}
```

#### Common Example Code

```js
import functions from "firebase-functions";
import { HttpsError } from "firebase-functions/lib/providers/https";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import hash from "object-hash";

admin.initializeApp();

interface AttachmentData {
  /** May contain a URL to the resource */
  url?: string;
  /** May contain Base64 encoded data of resource */
  data?: string;
  /** Type of this resource */
  type: "image" | "video" | "social" | "web";
}

interface PostData {
  author: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  attachments: Record<string, AttachmentData>;
  postId: string;
}

interface CacheEntry<T = admin.firestore.DocumentData> {
  /** Time data was cached, as a Cloud Firestore Timestamp object */
  cachedAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp;
  /** Time data was cached, as a Cloud Firestore Timestamp object */
  expiresAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp;
  /** The ETag signature of the cached resource */
  eTag: string;
  /** The cached resource */
  data: T;
}

/**
 * Returns posts authored by this user as an array, from Firestore
 */
async function getLivePostsForAuthor(uid: string) {
  // fetch the data
  const posts = await admin.firestore()
      .collection('posts')
      .where('author', '==', uid)
      .limit(100)
      .get();

  // flatten the results into an array, including the post's document ID in the data
  const results: PostData[] = [];
  posts.forEach((postDoc) => {
    results.push({ postId: postDoc.id, ...postDoc.data() } as PostData);
  });
  return results;
}

/**
 * Returns posts authored by this user as an array, caching the result from Firestore
 */
async function getCachedPostsForAuthor(uid: string) {
  // Get the reference to the data's location
  const cachedPostsRef = admin.firestore()
      .doc(`_server/apiCache/${uid}/posts`) as admin.firestore.DocumentReference<CacheEntry<PostData[]>>;

  // Get the cache entry's data
  const cachedPostsSnapshot = await cachedPostsRef.get();

  if (cachedPostsSnapshot.exists) {
    // get the expiresAt property on it's own
    // this allows us to skip processing the entire document until needed
    const expiresAt = cachedPostsSnapshot.get("expiresAt") as CacheEntry["expiresAt"] | undefined;
    if (expiresAt !== undefined && expiresAt.toMillis() > Date.now() - 60000) {
      // return the entire cache entry as-is
      return cachedPostsSnapshot.data()!;
    }
  }

  // if here, the cache entry doesn't exist or has expired

  // get the live results from Firestore
  const results = await getLivePostsForAuthor(uid);

  // etag, cachedAt and expiresAt are used for the HTTP cache-related headers
  // only expiresAt is used when determining expiry

  const cacheEntry: CacheEntry<PostData[]> = {
    data: results,
    eTag: hash(results),
    cachedAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
    // set expiry as 1 day from now
    expiresAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now() + 86400000),
  };

  // save the cached data and it's metadata for future calls
  await cachedPostsRef.set(cacheEntry);

  // return the cached data
  return cacheEntry;
}
```

#### HTTPS Request Function

This is the request type you would use for [serving Cloud Functions behind Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions). Unfortunately the implementation details aren't as straightforward as using a Callable Function (see below) but is provided as an [official project sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint). You will need to insert [`validateFirebaseIdToken()`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/2531d6d1bd6b16927acbe3ec54d40369ce7488a6/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L69) from that example for this code to work.

```js
import express from "express";
import cookieParserLib from "cookie-parser";
import corsLib from "cors";

interface AuthenticatedRequest extends express.Request {
  user: admin.auth.DecodedIdToken
}

const cookieParser = cookieParserLib();
const cors = corsLib({origin: true});
const app = express();

// insert from https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/2531d6d1bd6b16927acbe3ec54d40369ce7488a6/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L69
const validateFirebaseIdToken = /* ... */

app.use(cors);
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  // if here, user has already been validated, decoded and attached as req.user
  const user = (req as AuthenticatedRequest).user;

  try {
    const cacheEntry = await getCachedPostsForAuthor(user.uid);

    // set caching headers
    res
      .header("Cache-Control", "private")
      .header("ETag", cacheEntry.eTag)
      .header("Expires", cacheEntry.expiresAt.toDate().toUTCString());

    if (req.header("If-None-Match") === cacheEntry.eTag) {
      // cached data is the same, just return empty 304 response
      res.status(304).send();
    } else {
      // send the data back to the client as JSON
      res.json(cacheEntry.data);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof HttpsError) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      throw new HttpsError("unknown", err && err.message, err);
    }
  }
});

export const getMyPosts = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

#### Callable HTTPS Function

If you are making use of the client SDKs, you can also request the cached data using [Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

This allows you to export the function like this:

```js
export const getMyPosts = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      'failed-precondition',
      'The function must be called while authenticated.'
    );
  }

  try {
    const cacheEntry = await getCachedPostsForAuthor(context.auth.uid);
    return cacheEntry.data;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof HttpsError) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      throw new HttpsError("unknown", err && err.message, err);
    }
  }
});
```

and call it from the client using:

```js
const getMyPosts = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getMyPosts');
getMyPosts()
  .then((postsArray) => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle errors
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! So when you set the cache to ‘private’, that only lives in the browser and not the firebase hosting CDN. Which now makes sense... So if you just wanted it to cache in the browser for say a minute, would the way to do this be `res.header(‘Cache-Control’, ‘private, max-age=60’)`?

Comment: Yes @JoeBayLD, a 60s expiry would be set that way. However, in the code above, instead of using [`max-age`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#expiration) which gives a relative expiry time, I make use of the [`Expires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires) header instead to specify a fixed expiry time. Also make sure you use `'` not `‘’` as you may end up with a confusing syntax error.

Comment: Right on. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, one last thing, if you want the client to assume the copy they have in their cache is perfectly valid up until it actually expires (so it doesn't call your function with a "is this copy I have the latest copy?" request), add [`immutable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#revalidation_and_reloading) to the `Cache-Control` header. This is [not respected by Chromium browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_cache-control_immutable) as it's a contested feature, but might be helpful to include for reducing hits on your API from Firefox/Safari users.

Comment: Good to know! Also - while on the firebase side of things, have you used the __session cookie? The docs say that setting this allows you to cache per user? But I’m pretty unsure how this is set / used.

Comment: For what you are doing at the moment, the private browser cache would be preferred. The significance of the `__session` cookie is that it is the only cookie sent through to your function after passing through the CDN, all other cookies are ignored/discarded. If it's used for a request that does get cached by the CDN, it's automatically added to the signature of the CDN's cache entry so two different `__session` cookies can't access each other's data. In the linked sample, `__session` stored a Firebase ID token for authentication instead of the `Authorization` header.